# Finding the date of an allday event in google calendar

Tags: c#

I have a small C# program to read my Google Calender and return events.

```
public static IEnumerable<EventEntry> GetAllEvents(CalendarService service, DateTime? startData, DateTime? endData, int nbrToGet)
        {
            EventQuery query = new EventQuery();        // Create the query object:

            if (startData != null)
            {
                query.StartTime = startData.Value;
            }

            if (endData != null)
            {
                query.EndTime = endData.Value;
            }

            query.SortOrder = CalendarSortOrder.ascending;

            query.Uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/" + service.Credentials.Username + "/private/full" + "?max-results=" + nbrToGet.ToString());

            EventFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);       // Tell the service to query:

            return calFeed.Entries.Cast<EventEntry>();
        }
```

I do a foreach on the returned events to display the event details:

```
foreach (var q in myevents)
            {
                var one = q.Title.Text;
                var two = q.Times.ToList();

                if (two.Count > 0)
                {
                    a1 = two[0].StartTime.ToString();
                    a2 = two[0].EndTime.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    a1 = string.Empty;
                    a2 = string.Empty;
                }

                var three = q.Content.Content;

                test.Add(new MyCalendarData { Title = one, StartTime = a1, EndTime = a2, Content = three });
            }
```

On all day events, there is no Start time or End time. Is there a way to find the date associated with the event?

Comment: There should be something in the Times collection, no?  It won't have a start/end time; but there should be something in there with the AllDay flag set, no?

Comment: Thank you, that is correct. I found it in Recurrence.Value, I just have to pull it out of a string